# Laravel project shows This page isn’t working ,68.183.89.5 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 on ubantu Server Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, laravel, ubuntu

I Move my Laravel project on a Linux server and also set

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in my index.php file but still, it shows this

> This page isn’t working ,68.183.89.5 is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500

someone help me to solve this error.

Comment: Do you check your php version?

Comment: Did you check your application logs?

Comment: yes i update my php version

Comment: my php version is  7.3.15

Comment: Check your log files